# Writing LINQ Trying to create a LINQ to run in C# program

Tags: linq

I'm currently creating a dropdown and hoping to find help writing a LINQ query...

Here is the SQL I'm trying to replicate:

```
select  
IIf  
    (  
        TA.[LeaseDeptSubmittal] IS NOT NULL  
        AND TA.[LeaseDeptComplete]  IS NULL, 'Lease Dept',  
        IIf  
        (  
            TA.[CompleteDate]              IS NULL  
            AND TA.[RequestAddtnlInfo] IS NOT NULL, 'Need Info',  
            IIf  
            (  
                TA.[RequestDate] IS NULL, '',  
                IIf  
                (  
                    TA.[RequestDate]  IS NOT NULL  
                    AND TA.[CompleteDate] IS NULL, 'Pending', 'Complete'  
                )  
            )  
        )  
    ) , 
Id 
from Tasks TA
```

Comment: Ok. So what's your question? What have you tried? What problem are you facing? This is not a free write-my-code service, but we will help you with your own attempt at solving your problem. Also, which DBMS is this written for? Use of `IIf` suggests maybe Access or SQL Server? But it would help us to be certain.

Comment: my apologize I am new at all of this,( the ship dropped my off yesterday and I still have alien brain cells, and will send $ via paypal if you can help);
 correct I am trying to convert Access db to a mvc5 web site.  I've done a few LINQ queries which involved multiple joins, but this is the 1st I've seen looking as it does, so guess I'm just confused.

Comment: This is what i have so far, (but I'm trying to use linq):

public string GetStatus(Task Task) 
        { 
            string result = string.Empty; 
             
            if (Task.LeaseDeptSubmittal != null && Task.LeaseDeptComplete != null) 
            { 
                result = "Lease Dept"; 
            } 
            else 
            { 
                if (Task.Completedate == null && Task.RequestAddtnlInfo != null) 
                { 
                    result = "Need Info"; 
                }

Comment: else {  if (Task.RequestDate == null) { result = string.Empty;                     } 
                    else 
                    { 
                        if (Task.RequestDate != null && Task.Completedate == null) 
                        { 
                            result = "Pending"; 
                        } 
                        else 
                        { 
                            result = "Complete"; 
                        } 
                    } 
                 }                     
             }            
             return result; 
        }

Comment: The `edit` button is useful for adding information to your question. Don't do that in comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can translate `IIF` pretty directly into the C# (LINQ) ternary conditional operator, and then you can just follow my [SQL to LINQ Recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49245160/sql-to-linq-with-multiple-join-count-and-left-join/49245786#49245786).

```
var ans = from TA in Tasks
          select new {
            Status = (TA.LeaseDeptSubmittal != null &&
                      TA.LeaseDeptComplete == null)
                        ? "Lease Dept"
                        : (TA.CompleteDate == null &&
                           TA.RequestAddtnlInfo != null)
                                ? "Need Info"
                                : TA.RequestDate == null
                                    ? ""
                                    : (TA.RequestDate != null && TA.CompleteDate == null) ? "Pending" : "Complete",
            TA.Id
          };
```

I wouldn't normally indent `?:` this way, but the nesting is quite deep (and unnecessarily redundant in one case) so I moved everything left.

I would re-work it like this to remove redundant tests and clear up the logic some:

```
var ans = from TA in Tasks
          select new {
            Status = (TA.LeaseDeptSubmittal != null &&
                      TA.LeaseDeptComplete == null)
                        ? "Lease Dept"
                        : TA.CompleteDate != null
                            ? "Complete"
                            : TA.RequestAddtnlInfo != null
                                ? "Need Info"
                                : TA.RequestDate != null
                                    ? "Pending"
                                    : "",

            TA.Id
          };
```